# How to export a cookie in a file to use with python scrapy

Tags: python, cookies, scrapy

I want to login automatically to SO with my cookie using scrapy and python.
But i don't know

1. How to export cookie to what format so that i can use it with scrapy
2. There are many cookies listed in chrome for stackoverflow like this

Now which one to use for login
`__qca_ _utma_ _utmb_ _utmc __utmz gauthedsgt usrLocal storage`

3.What will be in that file and how to use that in Scrapy code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your cookie when you create first request to the server, as said on [this page](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html):

```
request_with_cookies = Request(url="http://www.example.com",
                           cookies={'currency': 'USD', 'country': 'UY'})
```

If you don't want which cookie is important for auth, use all of them or try to use one of them. Also check that [CookiesMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#cookies-mw) is enabled to get your cookies preserved in further requests.

If you want to use cookies stored in a file I suggest you to write simple parser of this file and convert file contents to python dict. As long as your file is in simple plain text format, this will be easy.

Comment: but how can i get what things to enter where you wrote `currenncy` , country. are those cookie names and USB value of it

Comment: Keys of this dict (`currency`, `country`) are cookie names. So your key or keys should be some of this: `__qca_ _utma_ _utmb_ _utmc __utmz gauthedsgt usrLocal storage`. Values of this dict are relevant cookie values.